# tictactoe java rmi connection refused

Tags: java, rmi

I have a client server code for a distributed TicTacToe game implemented in Java RMI. I am able to run my code on single machine, weather it is a Windows OS or Linux OS. 
But if try to run server(alongwith `rmireigstry`) on one machine and client on other machine, getting exception of `connectionRefused`.

[image]

Following is the screenshot of the exception:
Now, I tried to search and apply all the solutions that were given on google and stackoverflow.
I applied following solutions like :

1. Added `hostname` and coresponding IP to `/etc/hosts` file
2. set the property through `System.property("java.rmi.server.hostname","IP-Address of host")`.
3. Also run following command while executing server file : `java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/filepath/Desktop/my.policy TicTacToeImpl`

Still getting connection refused exception on client machine.

I need help to execute my tictactoe game on multiple linux machines by getting rid of above error.

Comment: Code and stack trace please. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- you haven't started the registry or the server
- the target address is wrong at the client
- you need to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the server JVM and you haven't.